# React native android autorotate issue

Tags: android, react-native, orientation

I want my application should be fixed to portrait orientation. but when I enable the auto-rotate in mobile, my application can able to rotate portrait and landscape. even I have added the `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` and `tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"` in the **AndroidManifest** file, it still allows rotation of the application.

Can anyone please help to fix my application has portrait orientation even auto-rotate enabled? I have searched on google. but no clue. please suggest to me some idea to fix this issue.

**AndroidManifest** file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:largeHeap="true"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
             <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity 
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"      android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
      
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you share your AndroidManifest file, I have done just what you said, and it worked for me.

Comment: Hi Akshay Shenoy, i have added the AndroidManifest file. Could you please check it and help me resolve this issue.

Comment: remove this line:  tools:ignore=”LockedOrientationActivity”,

and try again. i see 2 lines of it, try remove all.

Comment: why do you have **tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"**, can you remove it?

Comment: @AkshayShenoy I removed that code and tried, still i can able to rotate when i enable autorotate in my mobile. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed the issue. the problem was bottomstacknavigator. I have changed the createNativeStackNavigator to createStackNavigator. now issue has been resolved. thanks all your help.

Answer (score 0):

lets use this lib [react-native-orientation-locker](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-orientation-locker),
you can change to any orientation you want.

```
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation-locker';

Orientation.lockToPortrait();
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your answers. without any packages, is there any properties to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

another way
in **MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo; // <-- add this line

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  
  ...
   
  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); // <-- add this line
  
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I have added your code. but Still I can able to rotate the application.  any suggestion ?
```@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
```

Comment: lets rebuild from android-studio, may be cache.

Comment: yes. i rebuild and installed in my mobile, still facing the issue. 